# Pig User Defined Function (UDF) To Call A SOAP Web Service Client

Tags: apache-pig

Is it possible to write a Pig UDF that call a SOAP Web Service written in Java?  I am getting a syntax error when I run the Pig code below.  The UDF calls a Soap Web Services Client.

Pig Script:

```
register CalculatorWS_Client_Application.jar; 
A = LOAD 'student_data.txt' AS (name: chararray, age: int, gpa: float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE calculatorws_client_application.CalculateUDF(name);
Dump B;
```

Errors:

```
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: <file script.pig, line 3, column 23> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception:        org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1069: Problem resolving class version numbers for class calculatorws_client_application.CalculateUDF ....

Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1069: Problem resolving class version numbers for class calculatorws_client_application.CalculateUDF ...

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: calculatorws_client_application/CalculateUDF : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

2014-11-19 18:41:37,075 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1069: Problem resolving class version numbers for class calculatorws_client_application.CalculateUDF
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like java version mismatch.
Type java -version on the console and see what version it prints.
Also you can use sudo update-alternatives --config java and set version that you need.